# expressjs simple authentication - localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a function to check if a user is authenticated or not like this:-

```
app.use(compression({threshold:1}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({
   secret:'node.js app',
   resave:false,
   saveUninitialized:true,
   cookie:{secure:true}
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
function CheckAuth(req,res,next){
  if(!req.session.authenticated){
   res.redirect('/users/login');
   return;
  }
 next();
}
```

And used as a middleware

`app.use(CheckAuth);`

but the function running multiple times and multiple redirects and stops page load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to many redirects because the middleware also runs in `/users/login`
You should add that to your check in the middleware function.

```
function CheckAuth(req,res,next){
  if(!req.session.authenticated && req.url != '/users/login'){
   res.redirect('/users/login');
   return;
  }
 next();
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You need routing for '/users/login', otherwise you're redirected back to the same place and CheckAuth is called over and over in an endless loop.

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

You used the middleware for all routes so that the redirection loops forever.

So you need to specify which route need to be guarded explicitly. The code may be something like this:

```
//routes without auth guard
app.post('/users/login', login);
app.post('/users/register', register);

//routes guarded by auth
app.get('/api/xxx', CheckAuth, xxx);
app.post('/api/yyy', CheckAuth, yyy);
```